# Electrical Switches

Tags: switches

Sorry for the newbie question but am I correct to say both of these schematics are representative of (push button) switches? If not what is the difference between them? Do they work differently? Thanks in advance.

[image: switch 1]

[image: switch 2]

Comment: The bottom picture could be a relay contact (coil not shown).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The top one is a push button: Closed (making a connection) when you push it. As soon as you let go the contact opens again.
Example: the keys on your computer's keyboard

Bottom one is a toggle switch, you flip it, it stays closed even if you don't touch it anymore. It opens when you flip the switch again.
Example: the light switch in a room.

Answer (score 1):

The top one is normally open, but closed by pusing on the button. When you release the button, the contact is opened.

The bottom one is a switch that has two stable positions, one open and one closed, like the ones we use to turn the light on or off.

Answer (score 0):

The top one is a momentarily  switch, since its only connected momentarily.

The bottom one is a Maintained switch, the connection is basically maintain until it is modified.

You can also check the Momentary vs. Maintained section in this [switch basics tutorial from sparkfun](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/switch-basics)